# Microsoft.Expression.Blend.WindowsPhone.targets missing

Tags: msbuild, expression-blend, windows-phone-7

I'm having troubles opening some Windows Phone Mango RC projects in Visual Studio. The error message I get is:

```
The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Expression\
Blend\WindowsPhone\v7.1\Microsoft.Expression.Blend.WindowsPhone.targets" 
was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, 
and that the file exists on disk.
```

Looking in my file system that file is deff missing. I only got "v7.0" under the Blend\WindowsPhone folder. I have tried re-installing the Windows Phone 7.1 SDK RC release, but with no luck.

Anyone else ran into this issue or got tips on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it might be a problem with your installation. I have the Mango RC installed and I have three files in that directory:

```
 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Expression\Blend\WindowsPhone\v7.1

18/01/2011  00:03               521 Microsoft.Expression.Blend.WindowsPhone.targets
01/07/2011  04:43            44,544 SubsetFontTask.dll
18/01/2011  00:03             1,410 SubsetFontWindowsPhone.targets
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the above mentioned directory on my machien running Mango either but I can successfully build and run Mango projects.

Check the imports section of the project file to see what it's looking for.

Comment: I did, and it do try to import it, and two of the other guys on the team do have the file. Copied it across and now works. Not sure why it is missing.